# Sign of $P(Δ)$ with $P(x)=ax²+bx+c$ and $Δ=b²-4ac$

Tags: quadratics

Let $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ be a polynomial with $a≥0$ and $b≥\frac{1}{8a}$, and $Δ=b^2-4ac$. Show that $P(Δ)≥0$.

My answer: We have $Δ=b^2-4ac$. If$Δ≤0$, then $P(Δ)≥0$. If $Δ>0$, there are two cases:

If $c≥0$, $P(Δ)=aΔ^2+bΔ+c≥0$. If $c<0,Δ=b^2-4ac$ then $Δ>b^2$ and $Δ>-4ac$, then
$$P(Δ)=aΔ^2+bΔ+c>a×(-4ac)^2+b^3+c=16a^3c^2+c+b^3$$
is of degree two of variable $c$. We have $Δ_1=1-4×16a^3b^3=1-(4ab)^3$, which is negative if $b≥\frac{1}{4a}$ or we have $b≥\frac{1}{8a}$.

I want the correct solution of the exercise.

Comment: What is your question? Is this a solution verification?

Comment: Also, is it $b\geq \frac{1}{8a}$ or $b\geq \frac{1}{8}\cdot a$?

Comment: yes  Is this a solution verification, but my answer is not correct

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the solution of the exercise

Comment: You still need to prove that $P(\Delta) \geq 0$ if $\Delta \leq 0$. i.e. You need to show that $a\Delta^{2} \geq b \Delta + c$

Comment: if $\Delta \leq 0$ a≥0 so the sign of P is the sign of a which is positive

Comment: @connaissant the statement you just made of "if $\Delta \leq 0$ $a \geq 0$ so the sign of $P$ is the sign of $a$ which is positive" is not true in general. You have to prove it!

Comment: @Kendall If $\,\Delta \lt 0\,$ the quadratic has no real roots, so it must have the same sign for all $\,x \in \mathbb R\,$, and that must be the sign of $\,a\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I see I misread part of the question that lead me to an incorrect conclusion. You are indeed correct.

Answer (score 2):

Completing the square differently, this is non-negative when $\,a \gt 0\,$, $\,\Delta \ge 0\,$, $\,2b - \dfrac{1}{4a} \ge 0\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a} P(\Delta) &= \Delta^2+\frac{b}{a}\Delta \color{red}{-2 \frac{b}{a}\Delta + \frac{b^2}{4a^2} + 2 \frac{b}{a}\Delta - \frac{b^2}{4a^2}}+\frac{c}{a}
\\ &= \Delta^2 - 2 \frac{b}{2a}\Delta + \frac{b^2}{4a^2}+\frac{2b}{a}\Delta-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}
\\ &= \left(\Delta - \frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + \left(2 b - \frac{1}{4a}\right)\frac{\Delta}{a}
\end{align}
$$